# Imported Templates not working on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am quite new to Mediawiki and am trying to get templates work.

I managed to get a [simple one working](http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Template:Cita_conferenza/TemplateData) but the templates are shown in a weird way but no error is provided.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your template:

http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php?title=Template:Cita_conferenza

And it invokes a LUA module:

http://wordpress-251650-782015.cloudwaysapps.com/wiki/Modulo:Citazione

You can read more information about using this module on

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo:Citazione

Comment: How do I understand if I am lacking of LUA or of that second module?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to export a Module but I'm not sure on what it is

Comment: The LUA module seems to work, if you put in invalid values like `{{#invoke:Citazione|test}}` it displays an error `Script Error: The "test" function does not exist.`

Comment: Koopsman: what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

@Revious

A bit late, but you may still be interested...

If you want to copy a template from Wikipedia, but it is using lua modules, you can look in the history tab to find pre-lua versions that use only wikicode (lua has been implemented in 2013 in Wikipedia, but some templates have been given modules later).

Here, it seems to be [this version](https://it.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Cita_conferenza&action=edit&oldid=59449854)

Be careful, however, if the template you are copying uses subtemplates (this does not seem to be the case here).
If this is the case, you should either make copies of the templates with the same name and code, or add their code to the main template, paying attention to the parameter names which will need to be adapted.

Good luck.